# INSERTで被らないようDUPLICATEした時のauto_incrementがおかしい

Tags: python

<s>IDがauto_incrementの場合で

よく被ることがあるデータをINSERT DUPLICATEしているのですが、IDが重複してしまいます。</s>

なので被らない文字列（NAME)があったとして、
文字数の不規則な文字列から被らない10文字程度の数字にするにはどうすればいいですか？

```
ID int primary_key auto_increments unsgned, NAME varchar(255), C varchar(255)
```

Pythonで文字数の不規則な文字列から被らない10文字の数値にするにはどうすればいいですか？

結果

```
# 1.py
s = 'a'
abs(hash(s)) % (10 ** 8)
print(s)
# 22312233

#python 1.py
33123311

#python 1.py
21039122

#このように変化してはいけない。
```

理想

```
#python 1.py
88118800

#python 1.py
88118800
```

Comment: 参考 URL: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16008760

Comment: そちらの`abs(hash(s)) % (10 ** 8)`だと、ランダム整数になってしまい、実行するごとに値が変わってしまいます。

Comment: こちらの環境(Python 2.7.1) では `abs(hash('a')) % (10 ** 8)` は `68864544` になります(変化しません)。

Comment: こちらの環境(Python 3.5.1)では変数にしなくても'a'でも変化しました。

Comment: Python 3.5.2 では `92867412` で一定です。

Comment: 構文は`print(abs(hash('a')))%(10**8)`でこれをPython実行すると値は変化して生きます。

Comment: `for i in range(1,10): print(abs(hash('a')) % (10 ** 8))` を実行するとどうなりますか？

Comment: その場合、Pythonを実行するごとにIDが変わってしまいます。Pythonを実行するごとに固定された文字数で

Comment: 判りました、環境変数 `PYTHONHASHSEED` を `0` に設定すると変化しなくなります。例えば、`PYTHONHASHSEED=0 python3` として起動するなどします。

Comment: ありがとうございました、解決いたしました。

Comment: そもそも「被らない10文字の数値」を取得するのが目的でhashを使うのは不適切では？hashはユニークな値を生成しているわけではないですよね？